# Unit and Integration tests how to handle separate projects under VSTS?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, azure-devops

When implementing Unit tests and Integration tests, as I understood we are supposed to create a separate project within the same solution of the tested project.

**I don't understand how could I launch on the same Ci/Cd pipeline the 'tests', if we deal with two separate projects (one with my web application, the other one with the tests) and how the 'test' from Test Project could block the rest of the Ci/Cd pipeline for the Web App Project.**

Is it available if I put all my solution projects into the same remote repository?

I need some basic guidelines on what is correct way to handle this needs under VSTS

Here is my use case with ASP.NET Core :

1. I develop locally on my Feature branch (from Develop branch)
2. I commit, then push my Feature branch to the remote server (VSTS)
3. I PR my Feature branch to my Develop branch
4. If it works the CI/CD pipeline is triggered, the build of my Web application project is started: then on the CI pipeline I'm supposed to play all my tests (from Test Project)
5. If all the tests passed, I want the pipeline to continue then trigger the CD pipeline
6. If any test fails, I want the rest of the pipeline to be stopped

Comment: You can configure tests to run automatically then add on success triger for web application. In this way if your tests fail your web application wont be built or deployed

Comment: It works if the tests are in the same repository as the project, but if it's not how could we do considering the 'Get sources' process deal with only one repo ? Should both project be in the same repo then ?

Comment: Idealy complete solution should be in same repository... As different projects may depend on others... Like unit test project will depend on the project which you are going to test.

Comment: can you clarify with what exactly you are having issues with? You just need the .NET Core (Preview) build task (from VSTS build stemps templates) and configure the path to your unit test projects, i.e. `test/**/*.csproj` if your unit test projects are located in **test** sub folder otherwise use something like `**/*.Tests.csproj` if your csproj files are surfixed with `.Test`. And on that very same task you click on "Control Options" and you will have a checkbox "Continue on error". make sure its **unchecked**

Comment: Well to my first approach both projects were in separate repositories, so I wasn't able to figure out how to sync both repo in my Ci pipeline. But as you mentioned they should be in the same repository. I do understand then how to handle the test execution. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, your tests should be in separate *projects* but not separate *solutions*. There's no real way to split a solution into different repos, so that sort of necessitates that they are in fact in the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the test project/solution into the same repository (not recommended), just create new folder and copy test projects in that folder, then commit and push changes.

The better way is that you can retrieve the test project during the build:

1. Edit build definition
2. Select a phase and click **Allow scripts to access OAuth token** option
3. Add **Command Line** task (Tool: `git`; Arguments: `clone https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@XXX.visualstudio.com/[team project]/_git/[repository] [target folder name]`; Working folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`)
4. (Optional)Add build task to build test project
5. Build task to build web project
6. Publish/deploy task to publish web project or call command to run web app.
7. Test task to do test.
8. Other tasks